# Number theory with positive integer $n$ question

Tags: number-theory

If $n$ is a positive integer, what is the smallest value of $n$ such that $$(n+20)+(n+21)+(n+22)+ ... + (n+100)$$ is a perfect square?
I don't even now how to start answering this question.

Comment: The most obvious place to start is probably to compute the sum. (well, that becomes obvious if you've already taken the step to classify what kind of sum that is)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write it as $81n+\frac{81}{2}(100+20)=81(n+60)$

$81$ is a perfect square. For what least $n$ is $60+n$ a perfect square?

> $n=4$

Comment: Did you use a formula to get that statement? If so, which one?

Comment: @user108104 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression

Comment: Ok I just got confused because you swapped the 100 and 20 around.

Answer (score 2):

separate out the constant and variable so we get $81/2\cdot120 = 4860$
and $81\cdot n$.
We are now looking for the closest perfect squares such that when $4860$ is subtracted from it the difference is a multiple of $81$.

Now closest to $4860$ we have
$$\begin{align*}
70^2 & =4900 \\
71^2 &=5041 \\
72^2 &= 5041 
\end{align*}$$

Now $5041-4860 = 324 = 81\cdot 4$ so the least value of $n$ to make the above expression a perfect square is $n=4$.

Good question!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE I have taken the time to improve your answer by adding LaTeX to improve readability. Very nice first answer ;)

Comment: Thanks I have a rather messy habit of scribbling while solving

Comment: No problem. I suggest you read the MathJax tutorial so you can do this yourself in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Let $$f(n) = (n+20)+(n+21)+(n+22)+ ... + (n+100)=81n+\frac{100\cdot101}{2}-\frac{19\cdot20}{2}=81n+4860=81(n+60)$$
Now since $81$ is already a perfect square you have to find the smallest $n$ for which $n+60$ is a perfect square too...$\Rightarrow n=4$ and $f(n) = 72^2$

Answer (score 0):

Although equation:

$(n+20)+(n+21)+...+(n+100)=81(n+60)=81y^2$

Solutions have the form:

$y=\frac{k+1}{2}$

$n=\frac{k^2+2k-239}{4}$

$k$ - can be any character.